# Converting texts to foreign keys when importing data with Django excel

Tags: django, django-views, django-excel

**Tbl.1**

| id | **author** | brand_id | name | barcode | unit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | user1 | TestBrand1 | Product1 | TST1234 | 700 |
|  | user2 | TestBrand2 | Product2 | TST5678 | 380 |

I have an excel spreadsheet as in the example above. The `author` and `brand_id` in the table fields represent the foreignkey fields in the model.

When the user wants to add a product to the system with excel, he/she has to enter the author and the brand as strings. Like the table in the example above.

But since `author` and `brand_id` are foreign keys, excel should be like this.`

**Tbl.2**

| id | **author** | brand_id | name | barcode | unit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | 1 | 1 | Product1 | TST1234 | 700 |
|  | 2 | 2 | Product2 | TST5678 | 380 |

My question is how can I dynamically convert the author and brand data received as strings as a foreign key on the database and save it.

For example, if `brand_id` = TestBrand1, I want to record the id of that brand on the database.(As in **Tbl.2**)

**Here my Product models:**

```
class Product(models.Model):
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
author = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete= models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Product Author', null=True)
brand_id = models.ForeignKey(Brand,on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Brand Names")
name = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name="Product Name",unique=True)
barcode = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name="Barcode")
unit = models.CharField(max_length=255,verbose_name="Product Unit") 

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

**Here my product views:**

```
@login_required(login_url="login")
def addProduct(request):
    . 
    .
    .
    .
    .
        elif 'save_file' in request.POST:
            dataset = Dataset()
            new_products = request.FILES['product_file']
            if not new_products.name.endswith('xlsx'):
                messages.info(request,'Wrong file format!')
                return redirect(".")

            imported_data = dataset.load(new_products.read(), format='xlsx')
            for data in imported_data:
                values = Product(
                    data[0],
                    data[1],
                    data[2],
                    data[3],
                    data[4],
                    data[5],
                )
                values.save()
            messages.success(request,"Product added from file succesfully!")
            return redirect("products")
                
    context = {
        .
        .
        .
        .
    }
    return render(request,"product/addproduct.html",context)
```

Thank you for your help, best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I couldn't find a method for this, I solved it in a hardcoing way.

Comment: It would be helpful for others facing the same if you added some example code in your answer. :)

Comment: I'll code an example and add it to the answer at the first available time. :)